# Converting My Data to CiviCRM data formats

Tags: import

When importing data into CiviCRM, do I need to reformat my data in any way so that it is in conformance with CiviCRM data formats?

Comment: Have you seen https://docs.civicrm.org/user/en/stable/common-workflows/importing-data-into-civicrm/ ?

Answer (score 6):

one thing I have found has helped me and many others is to do an export from CiviCRM of a sample set of the fields you are going to import, then you can see how civicrm expects fields, tags and other data structures.